# フェードインしてフェードアウトするアニメーション処理に適切な名前をつけたい

Tags: untagged

```
func フェードインしてからフェードアウト {
  フェードイン()
  5秒表示
  フェードアウト()
}
```

`アンドロイド`の`トースト`のようにフェードインして来てしばらく表示されその後フェードアウトしていくアニメーションに適切な名前はありますでしょうか？

http://www.moon-light.ne.jp/termi-nology/meaning/fade-in.htm
上記URLにヒントになりそうなのがありそうでしたが、今回求めているものはありませんでした...

> ちなみに、主に音声でフェードイン、フェードアウトを同時に行なうこと、 つまり一方の音を徐々に絞り、もう一方を徐々に大きくすることを
>   「クロスフェ－ド」(cross fade)と言います。 そして同様のことを映像で行う場合、
>   つまり映像が徐々に消えていく中、次の映像が徐々に現れてくるのを 「ディゾルブ」(dissolve)、 そしてこの二つの映像を重ねてしまうのを
>   「オーバーラップ」(over lap)と言います。

`トースト`のようによく知られた名称のついた部品だと良いのですが、今回はもっと一般的にフェードインしてフェードアウトして消えていく一般的な名称を求めております。

Comment: カムアンドゴーとかそのような感じですか？[http://www.wordreference.com/jaen/現れてはすぐ消える] すぐになくなるという意味では、be fleeting はかない。と書いてあります。はかなさと言い換えてもよろしければの話ですが・・・。

Comment: @Haru なるほど。「来て去っていく」というより「来て戻っていく」のイメージのほうが（あくまで私のイメージに）近そうです。

Comment: 一般的な名称というのは、どこかのプログラミング言語で使われているそういう意味を意図して名付けられた名前はないか？ということですか？それともどんな英語でもピタッと来るものがあればよろしいですか？`wave and return`（波が寄せては返す）とか、来て戻っていくという感じですが・・・。どうしても2動作ありますので、熟語っぽくなりますね。fetch(行って取って来る)みたいなものもあるみたいなので、探してみます。

Comment: @Haru 私が質問文にかいたURLですと、演劇に関するページのようです。このようにどんな英語でもピタッとくるものがくると好ましいのですが、やはりshowやhideになると、プログラム中に別の意味で使われていることがありそうなので、ピタッとくればなんでもよいかというと難しいところではあります...。ご提示いただいたものは特にカムアンドゴーは、とても回答に近そうに感じます。

Comment: 探してみて、`StackExchange`の英語質問版でも聞いてみたんですが、ピッタリの言葉はないようです。`pulse`という意外な答えが返ってきました。一応報告しておきます。自分でも色々と造語をひねってみたのですが、どうしても長くなります。

Comment: @Haru なさそうなのは残念ですね。ご協力ありがとうございます。

Comment: すいません。最後に一つ確認させてください。そのアニメーションは、どういう効果を狙ってなされるものでしょうか？user17014さんがおっしゃるように、何らかの目的がありますか？ユーザーに何かを伝えたいのか、あるいは場面の切り替えですか？

Comment: @Haru どちらかというと今出てきました！って感じ（フェードイン）、後ろの要素が見えないですよねーひっこみますー（フェードアウト）って感じですね。

Comment: 更新しました。今更ですがご覧ください！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**更新**

前回よりかなりの期間が空きましたので、いまさら回答されても仕方がないかもしれませんが、

**fadecurve**というのがしっくりくるかと思います。
この言葉はネットで検索しても、どうやら通常の英単語としては存在しない単語のようです。

しかし、[PySide documentation 1.2.1 Phonon](https://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/phonon/Phonon.VolumeFaderEffect.html?highlight=fadecurve#PySide.phonon.PySide.phonon.Phonon.VolumeFaderEffect.FadeCurve)を見てましたら、
ここに、似た現象を表すために、fadecurveという言葉が使われています。

ただ、5秒間のインターバルについては、この言葉に含まれていないものと思いますので、
この言葉を軸にして、何かプラスされたらいかがかと思います。少し長くなるかもしれませんが、
fadeintervalcurveとかが適当なんじゃないかと思います。

**以前**

コメントに

> 「来て去っていく」というより「来て戻っていく」のイメージのほうが（あくまで私のイメージに）近そうです。
>
> どちらかというと今出てきました！って感じ（フェードイン）、後ろの要素が見えないですよねーひっこみますー（フェードアウト）って感じですね。

質問者様は、その動作現象自体に適切な名前をつけたい。という事で、「正確にそれを表現する英語が欲しい」という訳ではなさそうです。和製英語でも、中々そのような表現は見当たりませんでした。

私がこの二つのコメントを読んで感じたイメージとしては、**鳩時計**です。

`cuckoo_clock`

来て戻っていきます。今出てきました！後ろの要素が見えません。引っ込みます。
この５つの現象を全て満たしています。動きも、フェードイン、フェードアウトと言ってもいいかもしれません。鳩の方が若干早い気もしますが。余計な事を言えば、後ろの要素が見えなくなる流れも少し変な気もしますけど、とにかく見えなくなっているかなと。

結構英語圏の方達も、現象の特徴から勝手にイメージに合う言葉をコンピュータ関係の名前付けに付けてらっしゃるので、これはそんなに的外れの名前付けではないのではないかな。と感じています。

> キャメルケース（英: `camelcase`）は、複合語をひと綴りとして、要素語の最初を大文字で書き表すことをいう。キャメルケースとは、大文字が「らくだのこぶ」のように見えることからの命名である。
> [wikipedia-camelcase](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%83%A1%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9)

みたいな感じ。最初は、フェードイン、フェードアウトは、左か、あるいは右からスライドしてくると思っていましたが、縦の動きでも問題がなさそうに思えました。

コメントからはどのような目的（例えば鳩時計だと時刻を知らせる）があるのかは読み取れませんでしたので、純粋に行動だけで表現する語を選びました。

Answer (score 1):

私個人的な意見としては、アニメーションはあくまで属性だと思いますので、それをベースで名前を付けるのではなく、そのViewを表示する目的で名前を付けるべきかと思います。
アラートを出したいならalertionですし、注記ならannotation、通知であればnotification、警告ならwarningにします。
一時的にしか表示しないというのを名前で表現するのであればinstantをつけて表現します。

お求めの回答とは違うかもしれませんが、一意見として参考にしていただければと思います。
質問の目的とあまりにもずれている場合は回答を取り下げますので、コメントください。

Comment: おっしゃる通り、`トースト`のようにView自体に名前を付けられると良いわけですが、そのViewの内部処理としてフェードインとフェードアウトに名前を付けたいという場面を想定しております。質問の内容と離れているかとどうかというと、取り下げるレベルまで離れていないと私は考えます。

Comment: 主旨了解しました。お目汚し失礼しました。回答としてはこのままとさせていただきたいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

あえて1単語で表現するなら`fading`はいかがでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

「ちらつく」「ゆらめく」という意味の glimmer や flicker という単語がありますが、想定している効果が「じわっと出てきてじわっと消える」というものだと、イメージされる効果の変化スピード感が不釣り合いかな。あとは、「まばたく」という意味の blink …はHTML要素があったか。

上記いずれも、単発ではなく周期的な動作にこそ適切な気がしますね。

最終的には「このプロダクトではこのような効果を○○○と呼ぶ」という、用語集を作って解決する話かも。